# Notification text and title don't show anymore after JQuery upgrade

Tags: jquery, notify

After upgrading from jQuery 2.2.4 to 3.6.1, notifications stopped working. Now they are an empty balloon with the icon only, no title or text content.

No error identified by JMIGRATE 3.4.0.

From jQuery 3.6.1, this is the notification:

```
//auto hide notification
Notification.prototype.autoHideNotify = function (style, position, title, text) {
    var icon = "fa fa-adjust";
    if (style == "error") { icon = "fa fa-exclamation";
    } else if (style == "warning") { icon = "fa fa-warning";
    } else if (style == "success") { icon = "fa fa-check";
    } else if (style == "custom") { icon = "md md-album";
    } else if (style == "info") { icon = "fa fa-question";
    } else { icon = "fa fa-adjust";
    }
    $.notify({
        title: title,
        text: text,
        image: "<i class='" + icon + "'></i>"
    }, {
        style: 'metro',
        className: style,
        globalPosition: position,
        showAnimation: "show",
        showDuration: 0,
        hideDuration: 0,
        autoHideDelay: 5000,
        autoHide: true,
        clickToHide: true
    });
},
```

We are using Notify.JS: https://github.com/jpillora/notifyjs

We are getting this HTML:

```
<div class="notifyjs-corner" style="top: 0px; right: 0px;">
    <div class="notifyjs-wrapper notifyjs-hidable">
        <div class="notifyjs-arrow">
        </div>
        <div class="notifyjs-container" style="">
            <div class="notifyjs-metro-base notifyjs-metro-success">
                <div class="image" data-notify-html="image">
                    <i class="fa fa-check">
                    </i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The expected result is:

```
<div class="notifyjs-corner" style="top: 0px; right: 0px;">
    <div class="notifyjs-wrapper notifyjs-hidable">
        <div class="notifyjs-arrow" style="">
        </div>
        <div class="notifyjs-container" style="">
            <div class="notifyjs-metro-base notifyjs-metro-success">
                <div class="image" data-notify-html="image">
                    <i class="fa fa-check">
                    </i>
                </div>
                <div class="text-wrapper">
                    <div class="title" data-notify-html="title">
                        Success
                    </div>
                    <div class="text" data-notify-html="text">
                        Found 1 client
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As shown above, the output is missing `text-wrapper` class and its child where notification information should be.

At GitHub this is a known issue (https://github.com/jpillora/notifyjs/issues/138). To solve it change closing tags at `notify-metro.js`. This file is shown below, already modified regarding closing tags. But the problem remains (empty notification).

```
$.notify.addStyle("metro", {
    html:
        "<div>" +
            "<div class='image' data-notify-html='image'></div>" +
            "<div class='text-wrapper'>" +
                "<div class='title' data-notify-html='title'></div>" +
                "<div class='text' data-notify-html='text'></div>" +
            "</div>" +
        "</div>",
    classes: {
        success: {
        "color": "#fafafa !important",
        "background-color": "#81c868",
        "border": "1px solid #33b86c"
        },
        //Others classes
    }
});
```

I suspect that the problem is in the lines below, affected by some 3.x jQuery new rules.

```
$.notify({
    title: title,
    text: text,
    image: "<i class='" + icon + "'></i>"
}, {
```

The request is being made like below. It was inspected and returns correctly.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Controller/Action',
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    async: true,
    data: JSON.stringify({
        //input data
    }),
    success: function (response) {
        if (response.success) {
            $.Notification.autoHideNotify('success', 'top right', 'Success', response.responseText);
        }
        else {
            $.Notification.autoHideNotify('warning', 'top right', 'Warning', response.responseText);
        }
    },
    error: function () {            
        $.Notification.autoHideNotify('error', 'top right', 'Error', 'Default message')
        }
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you see when you inspect the content with your browser?

Answer (score 0):

```js
/* place into <script> (end of <body>) */

$(document).ready(function (){
    $.notify.addStyle("metro", {
      html:"<div class=\"notifyjs-corner\" >\n" +
              "    <div class=\"notifyjs-wrapper notifyjs-hidable\">\n" +
              "        <div class=\"notifyjs-arrow\" style=\"\">\n" +
              "        </div>\n" +
              "        <div class=\"notifyjs-container\" style=\"\">\n" +
              "            <div class=\"notifyjs-metro-base notifyjs-metro-success\">\n" +
              "                <div class=\"image\" data-notify-html=\"image\">\n" +
              "                    <i class=\"fa fa-check\">\n" +
              "                    </i>\n" +
              "                </div>\n" +
              "                <div class=\"text-wrapper\">\n" +
              "                    <div class=\"title\" data-notify-html=\"title\">\n" +
              "                        Success\n" +
              "                    </div>\n" +
              "                    <div class=\"text\" data-notify-html=\"text\">\n" +
              "                        Found 1 client\n" +
              "                    </div>\n" +
              "                </div>\n" +
              "            </div>\n" +
              "        </div>\n" +
              "    </div>\n" +
              "</div>",
      classes: {
        success: {
          "color": "#fafafa !important",
          "background-color": "#81c868",
          "border": "1px solid #33b86c"
        },
        //Others classes
      }
    });
    function autoHideNotify(style, position, title, text) {
      let icon = "fa fa-adjust";
      if (style == "error") { icon = "fa fa-exclamation";
      } else if (style == "warning") { icon = "fa fa-warning";
      } else if (style == "success") { icon = "fa fa-check";
      } else if (style == "custom") { icon = "md md-album";
      } else if (style == "info") { icon = "fa fa-question";
      } else { icon = "fa fa-adjust";
      }
      $.notify({
        title: title,
        text: text,
        image: "<i class='" + icon + "'></i>"
      }, {
        style: 'metro',
        className: style,
        globalPosition: position,
        showAnimation: "show",
        showDuration: 0,
        hideDuration: 0,
        autoHideDelay: 5000,
        autoHide: true,
        clickToHide: true
      });
    }


    $.ajax({
      url: '/Controller/Action',
      type: "POST",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      async: true,
      data: JSON.stringify({
        //input data
      }),
      success: function (response) {
        if (response.success) {
          autoHideNotify('success', 'top right', 'Success', response.responseText);
        }
        else {
          autoHideNotify('warning', 'top right', 'Warning', response.responseText);
        }
      },
      error: function () {
        autoHideNotify('error', 'top right', 'Error', 'Default message')
      }
    });
  })
```

```html
<!--place into <head> -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/notifyjs/notifyjs/master/dist/notify.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-xh6O/CkQoPOWDdYTDqeRdPCVd1SpvCA9XXcUnZS2FmJNp1coAFzvtCN9BmamE+4aHK8yyUHUSCcJHgXloTyT2A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
```

Comment: Sorry but I didn't get it. Those are 3 distinct files: JS for the page (with ajax request); JS for the autoHideNotify function (jQuery from CDN); JS for the ```addStyle``` (notify.js from CDN). Each page has their own JS file, therefore reaching the other 2 files. Joining them doesn't work for me. Also, the ```addStyle``` portion is with output already written, and ```rawgit.com``` is going offline (should already been gone).